# Koalas, Crabs, and Commapillars

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Given two positive integers X and Y, output any combination of the following three ASCII-art animals such that the output contains exactly X commas (`,`) and Y periods (`.`), if it is possible.

1. **Koala:** 1 comma, 2 periods

   ```
   <.,.>
   ```
2. **Crab:** 2 commas, 2 periods

   ```
   ,<..>,
   ```
3. **Commapillar:** 3 or more commas, 1 period

   ```
   <,,,.>
   ```

   or `<,,,,.>` or `<,,,,,.>` or `<,,,,,,.>` or `<,,,,,,,.>` etc.

If no combination of these animals can produce exactly X commas and Y periods, output a single commaleon who will camouflage the failure:

```
~<.,,>~~
```

The output animals can be in any amounts and any order. They may be in a string, space or newline separated, or else in a list where each animal is one element.

For example, for X = 7, Y = 5, these would all be valid outputs (separated by empty lines):

```
<.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,.>

<.,.>
<,,,,,.>
<.,.>

,<..>, <.,.> <,,,,.>

<,,,,.>
,<..>,
<.,.>

,<..>, <,,,.> ,<..>,

[",<..>,", ",<..>,", "<,,,.>"] (list syntax depends on language)
```

Note that (at least in this example) there are multiple sets of animals than can work. But remember you only need to output any *one* valid solution, if one exists. The number of animals or number of distinct animals does not matter.

For inputs such as X = 3, Y = 3 or X = 1, Y = 5 where there is no solution, the output will always be

```
~<.,,>~~
```

perhaps in a single-element list.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: The koala looks just like that :-)

Comment: I created a small programm that outputs the number of combinations for each pair (X, Y). Unfortunately, I could only run it up until (128, 128) because that's about the maximum for `__int128` and I was too lazy to use a bignum library. Here is the CSV dump: http://pastebin.com/ght5xkRu the first row and column are the X and Y values

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 139 bytes

Lambda function, takes x and y as arguments and returns a string

```
->x,y{c=y-2*n=y-(x>y ?1:0)>>1
x+=-c/2*s=[x-n,c*3].max
x<n||x>n*2?'~<.,,>~~':',<..>, '*(x-n)+'<.,.> '*(2*n-x)+"<%s.> "*c%[?,*s-=c/2*3,?,*3]}
```

If a solution exists, it can be done with all koalas+commapillars or all koalas+crabs.

The principle is to use a minimum of commapillars. If the number is odd, we use 1 commapillar. if even we use 0 commapillars, unless there are more commas than periods, in which case we use 2.

The number of periods used in noncommapillars (crabs + koalas) is necessarily even, and the number of noncommapillars is half `(number of periods)-(number of commapillars)`. If there are insufficient commas for all koalas, or too many for all crabs, no solution is possible. Otherwise, we return a solution.

**Commented in test program**

uses "fail" instead of chameleon for clarity

```
f=->x,y{c=y-2*n=y-(x>y ?1:0)>>1
#n=noncommapillars=y>>1 as they have 2 periods. c=commapillars=y-2*n, 1 for odd y, 0 for even y.
#if x>y there are too many commas to have 0 commapillars for even y. noncommapillars= y-1 >> 1, so 2 commapillars

x+=-c/2*s=[x-n,c*3].max
# s=number of commas allocated to commapillars. x-n to allow all noncommapillars to be koalas, but at least 3 per commapillar.
#-c/2 == -1 if there are commapillars, 0 if not (Ruby truncates toward -inf). Subtract commas for commapillars from x if necessary

x<n||x>n*2?'fail':',<..>, '*(x-n)+'<.,.> '*(2*n-x)+"<%s.> "*c%[?,*s-=c/2*3,?,*3]}
#if x<n (insufficient commas for all koalas) or x>n*2 (too many for all crabs) return fail. Else...
#return string off crabs, koalas, and (using % operator like sprintf) c commapillars (0..2), the second with 3 commas (if present) and the first with the rest.  



10.times{|j|10.times{|i|puts "%-20s %s"%[?.*j+?,*i,f[i,j]]}}
#all x,y from 0..9
```

**Output**

```
,                    fail
,,                   fail
,,,                  fail
,,,,                 fail
,,,,,                fail
,,,,,,               fail
,,,,,,,              fail
,,,,,,,,             fail
,,,,,,,,,            fail
.                    fail
.,                   fail
.,,                  fail
.,,,                 <,,,.>
.,,,,                <,,,,.>
.,,,,,               <,,,,,.>
.,,,,,,              <,,,,,,.>
.,,,,,,,             <,,,,,,,.>
.,,,,,,,,            <,,,,,,,,.>
.,,,,,,,,,           <,,,,,,,,,.>
..                   fail
..,                  <.,.>
..,,                 ,<..>,
..,,,                fail
..,,,,               fail
..,,,,,              fail
..,,,,,,             <,,,.> <,,,.>
..,,,,,,,            <,,,,.> <,,,.>
..,,,,,,,,           <,,,,,.> <,,,.>
..,,,,,,,,,          <,,,,,,.> <,,,.>
...                  fail
...,                 fail
...,,                fail
...,,,               fail
...,,,,              <.,.> <,,,.>
...,,,,,             <.,.> <,,,,.>
...,,,,,,            <.,.> <,,,,,.>
...,,,,,,,           <.,.> <,,,,,,.>
...,,,,,,,,          <.,.> <,,,,,,,.>
...,,,,,,,,,         <.,.> <,,,,,,,,.>
....                 fail
....,                fail
....,,               <.,.> <.,.>
....,,,              ,<..>, <.,.>
....,,,,             ,<..>, ,<..>,
....,,,,,            fail
....,,,,,,           fail
....,,,,,,,          <.,.> <,,,.> <,,,.>
....,,,,,,,,         <.,.> <,,,,.> <,,,.>
....,,,,,,,,,        <.,.> <,,,,,.> <,,,.>
.....                fail
.....,               fail
.....,,              fail
.....,,,             fail
.....,,,,            fail
.....,,,,,           <.,.> <.,.> <,,,.>
.....,,,,,,          <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,.>
.....,,,,,,,         <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,.>
.....,,,,,,,,        <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,,.>
.....,,,,,,,,,       <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,,,.>
......               fail
......,              fail
......,,             fail
......,,,            <.,.> <.,.> <.,.>
......,,,,           ,<..>, <.,.> <.,.>
......,,,,,          ,<..>, ,<..>, <.,.>
......,,,,,,         ,<..>, ,<..>, ,<..>,
......,,,,,,,        fail
......,,,,,,,,       <.,.> <.,.> <,,,.> <,,,.>
......,,,,,,,,,      <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,.> <,,,.>
.......              fail
.......,             fail
.......,,            fail
.......,,,           fail
.......,,,,          fail
.......,,,,,         fail
.......,,,,,,        <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,.>
.......,,,,,,,       <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,.>
.......,,,,,,,,      <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,.>
.......,,,,,,,,,     <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,,.>
........             fail
........,            fail
........,,           fail
........,,,          fail
........,,,,         <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <.,.>
........,,,,,        ,<..>, <.,.> <.,.> <.,.>
........,,,,,,       ,<..>, ,<..>, <.,.> <.,.>
........,,,,,,,      ,<..>, ,<..>, ,<..>, <.,.>
........,,,,,,,,     ,<..>, ,<..>, ,<..>, ,<..>,
........,,,,,,,,,    <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,.> <,,,.>
.........            fail
.........,           fail
.........,,          fail
.........,,,         fail
.........,,,,        fail
.........,,,,,       fail
.........,,,,,,      fail
.........,,,,,,,     <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,.>
.........,,,,,,,,    <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,.>
.........,,,,,,,,,   <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <.,.> <,,,,,.>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Befunge, <s>249</s> 218 bytes

```
&::00p&::00g\`-2/:20p2*-3*:30p\20g-`:!00g20g-*\30g*+:30g-v>:#,_@
"~<.,,>~~"0_v#\g03+`g050`\0:-g02\p05:-\*2g02:-*/6+3g03p04<^
$"<">:#,_40p>:!#|_3-0" >.,,"40g3>3g#<\#-:#1_
0" ,>..<,">:#,_$>:!#|_1-
#@_1-0" >.,.<">:#,_$>:!
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Jjo6MDBwJjo6MDBnXGAtMi86MjBwMiotMyo6MzBwXDIwZy1gOiEwMGcyMGctKlwzMGcqKzozMGctdj46IyxfQAoifjwuLCw-fn4iMF92I1xnMDMrYGcwNTBgXDA6LWcwMlxwMDU6LVwqMmcwMjotKi82KzNnMDNwMDQ8XgokIjwiPjojLF80MHA-OiEjfF8zLTAiID4uLCwiNDBnMz4zZyM8XCMtOiMxXwowIiAsPi4uPCwiPjojLF8kPjohI3xfMS0KI0BfMS0wIiA-LiwuPCI-OiMsXyQ-OiE&input=NyA1)

This is now based on the algorithm in the [Ruby answer](/a/101217/62101) by [Level River St](/users/15599/level-river-st), which provided greater scope for golfing and a significant reduction in size compared to my original solution.

Answer (score 2):

### C#6, <s>321</s> 303 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;string F(int x,int y)=>S(x,y)??"~<.,,>~~";string S(int x,int y)=>x<0|y<0?null:y<1?x<1?"":null:y*3>x?S(x-1,y-2)!=null?S(x-1,y-2)+"<.,.> ":S(x-2,y-2)!=null?S(x-2,y-2)+",<..>, ":null:string.Concat(new int[y].Select((_,k)=>k<1?C(x-y*3+3):C(3)));string C(int x)=>$"<{new string(',',x)}.> ";
```

Call `F()`. The other two functions are helpers. [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/E8ME/1)

```cs
// Coalesce failed combinations with commaleon
string F(int x,int y)=>S(x,y)??"~<.,,>~~";
// Get successful combination or null
string S(int x,int y)=>
    x<0|y<0
        // Fail: Out of range
        ?null
        :y<1
            ?x<1
                // Successful: All commas and periods accounted for
                ?""
                // Fail: Not enough periods for commas
                :null
            :y*3>x
                // Not all commapillars
                ?S(x-1,y-2)!=null
                    // Try koala
                    ?S(x-1,y-2)+"<.,.> "
                    // Try crab
                    :S(x-2,y-2)!=null
                        ?S(x-2,y-2)+",<..>, "
                        // Epic fail
                        :null
                // All commapillars
                :string.Concat(new int[y].Select((_,k)=>k<1
                    // This commapillar takes most of commas
                    ?C(x-y*3+3)
                    // The rest each takes 3
                    :C(3)));
// Generate single commapillar
string C(int x)=>$"<{new string(',',x)}.> ";
```